# Block access for traffic to fake PDF pages

Tags: .htaccess, pdf, http-status-code-404, block

I have a lot of 404 hits to my site to PDF pages that have never existed on the site. These are all spammy-subject.pdf URLs. I get tens of these per day, which is much higher than genuine site traffic.

I'm currently adding 410 rewrites for each.

Can I use htaccess rule to totally block this traffic from reaching this site? Before it becomes a 404?

Comment: Are you using a CMS? Please include your existing `.htaccess` file in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use htaccess rule to totally block this traffic from reaching this site?

You can use `.htaccess` to prevent the request from being routed through a CMS such as WordPress, Joomla, etc. that uses a front-controller pattern - if that's what you mean by "site". However, the request has already reached your *server* by the time the `.htaccess` file is processed, so doing anything in `.htaccess` isn't necessarily going to help a "static site".

If you are already returning a 404 (or 410) - before it reaches your *site* - then the issue is already resolved.

The only potential issue is if the requests are being routed through your CMS and the 404 is being triggered by your CMS, not Apache. This would suggest you have the directives in the wrong place in your `.htaccess` file (or not present at all)? Blocking directives like this need to be at the top of your `.htaccess` file, before any existing rewrites.

For example:

```
# Prevent 404 request being routed unnecessarily through CMS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.pdf$ - [NC,R=404]
```

There's no advantage to serving a 410 Gone instead of a 404 unless these files previously existed and you are trying to remove them from search engines (or telling 3rd parties they no longer exist).

**UPDATE:**

> Should this code be at the very top or after the opening Wordpress rule: RewriteEngine On ?

It needs to be at the very top, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker (you should avoid manually editing the code in the WordPress section since WordPress itself maintains this section and your edits will be overwritten).

Yes, this is before the `RewriteEngine On` directive. You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive. The location of the `RewriteEngine` directive does not actually matter. If there are multiple instances of this directive in the file then the *last* instance wins and controls the entire file. (It is a quick way to effectively comment out all the mod_rewrite directives in the file by simply placing a `RewriteEngine Off` directive at the very *end*.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the kind of answer I've been looking for. I assume the CMS is currently triggering the 404 as there's nothing like this in the .htaccess. I will try this code.

Comment: Should this code be at the very top or after the opening Wordpress rule: RewriteEngine On ?

Comment: @ElliotWalker It needs to be at the very top, _before_ the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker (you should never manually edit the code in the WordPress section). Yes, this is before the `RewriteEngine On` directive. You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive. (If there are multiple instances of this directive in the file then the _last_ instance wins and controls the entire file.)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think I've done it correctly because all random URLs with .pdf at the end go to a blank page with:
"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server."
Instead of the website generated 404 page.
Does that sound correct?

Comment: @ElliotWalker Yes, that sounds great. The request is rejected _before_ WordPress kicks in, so it saves some server resources. The "Not Found" message would be the default Apache response.